# Flask multithreading not actually starting seperate threads for each request

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm setting up an API with to talk to the backend of a platform I'm setting up, due to the way the platform works the backend can sometimes call the API while the current request is not fully processed. For this reason it is important that flask starts a new thread for each call made to the API.

The threading function in flask (`app.run(threaded=True`) is not actually giving the expected result. running the API with multiple processes does work but requires a predefined number of processes.I can't know how many embedded calls the user will make though and I would prefer to not limit this number

```py
@app.route("/call", methods=['POST'])
def call():
    #call to the backend that can cause a call to be made to the API

app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: What wsgi server do you use to run your app?

Comment: Currently just the default development version that comes with flask (I'm running by simply calling `python -m app` (the file is called app.py))

Comment: How you test app? Only look in task manager on number of threads? Or add some stress test? Because expected behavior is start next thread if current pool of thread is to small to handle all requests.